Hidden windows cannot be fetched in NSApp
Using purely swift programatically (no storyboard), I'm able to create an NSWindow like so:
var  window = NSWindow (contentRect: pInstruction.GetFrame (),
                    styleMask: [.miniaturizable, .closable, .resizable, .titled],
                    backing: .buffered,
                    defer: false)
window.title = "Some Title"
window.contentViewController = MyViewController ()
let windowidentifier = NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier ("WinID1")
window.identifier = windowidentifier

window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)

This works fine and I can see a window on screen. Later, when I want to access the window I can use a utility method:
 static func GetWindow(_ pWindowID: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier) -> NSWindow? {
        
        let windows = NSApp.windows
        for window in windows {
            if window.identifier == pWindowID {
                return window
            }
        }
        return nil
}

// Then I can call this function like so:

let windowidentifier = NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier ("WinID1")
let window = GetWindow (windowidentifier)

This also works fine.
However, if I do

window.setIsVisible(false)

or

window.orderOut (nil)

to temporarily hide the window, then NSApp.windows returns an empty array and I'm not able to find the window object and my Utility method "GetWindow ()" doesn't work.
Any suggestions on how I can find hidden windows?

Post a [mre] please.

You can use the snippets above in any swift file ("import Cocoa" is required).

I tried your code and I get the hidden window.
